# Rails 3.1, jQuery UI does not load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I am using Rails 3.1 and having an issue with the jQueryUI library. Here is my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails.validations

//= require_tree .
```

It loads the "jquery ui" file into the browser, but whatever I use related to it it shows this error:

```
TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'dialog'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of struggling with the issue, I finally removed `//= require jquery-ui` from `application.js` and added the new jQuery UI file, and everything works fine now. My new asset file is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery/jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails.validations

//= require_tree .
```

`jquery` is a sub-folder in my `javascripts` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems, `application.js` looked like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

In development mode, it seems `/assets/application.js` contained a version of jQuery bundled with ujs, and, when added to the page, it was like this:

```
<script src="jquery"></script>
<script src="jquery_ujs"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui"></script>
<script src="application.js"></script>
```

The last file was overriding the first three files. I put:

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery-ui
```

and it works fine.

The funny thing is, `application.js` only contains `require` lines, no jQuery or ujs.

Comment: Not sure why/how/when I'd removed `require_self` to begin with, but adding it back to the top fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might have precompiled your assets at an earlier point.
Try to remove everything under `public/assets`.