# RoR 3.2.6: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

currently I'm working on an older ruby on rails project.

In use:

- `ruby 2.2.10`
- `rails 3.2.6`
- `jquery-rails 3.1.5`
- `bootstrap-sass 2.3.2.2`
- `execjs 2.7.0`
- `therubyracer 0.12.3`

My console prints `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Then I tried to define `$ = jQuery` which printed `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` which means that jQuery is not properly included. I also read a lot of other posts about this issue but nothing has fixed mine so far.

**application.js (snippet)**

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require bootstrap
```

**application.html.erb (snippet)**

```
    <head>
      <title>Creative Title</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
```

There's nothing special in the dev console ... - it's driving me really crazy.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: you are not including jquery properly, or you are executing jquery code before jquery is loaded

Comment: Can you confirm, you're application.js contains
`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .`

Comment: I know that it's not loaded properly - I also tried to print `$` or `jQuery` to the console right after the `//= require` - but I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Sure I copied it straight from the editor.

Comment: You're post is missing `//= require_tree .`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Nope, I already had it in the original file - but one post recommended removing it. But it didn't work both ways.

Comment: Put your jquery code in $(document).ready(function () {//code}); and try and kindly let me know out put of $ or jQuery from your browser console.

Comment: Can you try `//= require jquery` `//= require jquery_ujs` `//= require bootstrap` `//= require_self` `//= require_tree .`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna already tried that. it's not working.  
@Anshul Well, jQuery is not loaded so that doesn't make quite sense. Output as expected: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Could you push the code to a repo and share the link ? if that's something possible.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Sorry that's not possible. :/ Closed source

Comment: No Problem, See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774389/rails-3-1-jquery-ui-does-not-load) helps.

Comment: Well I already fixed it but thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
I just cleared my gemset using `rvm gemset empty`,
created a new gemset `rvm gemset create <name>` (switched to that gemset)
and executed `bundle install` and `bundle update`
(after installing bundler oc: `gem install bundler`) which fixed that issue.

Quite strange but it works now. Neat.